# Generating a (relatively) large current from a small battery at 2 Hz?

Tags: low-power, current-source

So, I'm running into a few roadblocks and am seeking advice.

I'm trying to use a very small 6V battery to provide 1.5 mA at 2 Hz to a ~100k load.

I intend to use a small microprocessor and a BJT/MOSFET to regulate the frequency and application of current. However, what I'm struggling with is how to achieve this kind of current from such a small battery. I don't have much practical experience with electronics. Would it be feasible to use a capacitor to charge up while waiting for the "on" cycle? How can I regulate the current when the capacitor discharges?

Any advice to get me started a bit would be greatly appreciated. I've been researching a bit on constant current sources and I'm mostly struggling at the power supply aspect. I'm restricted to a very small battery for input.

Comment: At 6V your load resistance will need to be 1/25th of the resistance you have to get 1.5 mA

Comment: @MattYoung Say, a Duracell 28A or two CR2032's in series.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum could you provide a bit more insight on what you mean by that?

Comment: What is your load cycle: how long on and how long off?  A CR2032 battery is certainly capable of supplying 1.5 ma especially if the duty cycle is less than 100%.  What lifetime do you need from the battery? You have to answer these questions before we an answer yours. You also need to reconcile the disconnect between a 100k load vs 1.5 ma at 6 v.

Comment: You'll need to use a boot converter or similar to get enough voltage to drive 1.5 mA into 100k ohms.

Comment: Meaning, V/R = I, if you have 6 volts, and a 100k Ohm load, that yield ~60 micro Amps. Much smaller than the 1.5 mA you wanted. @alex.forencich's boost converter suggestion would work. but you'd need to get to 150 volts for that to work, which seems unlikley

Comment: @Barry 2 Hz. 50% duty cycle. Relatively low power consumption otherwise, just the microprocessor in idle. 50 + hours on the battery lifetime.

Comment: You need 150 volts to generate 1.5 mA through 100k ohms.  That's 0.225 watts.  At 50% duty cycle and 100% efficiency, that's 0.1125 watts.  To run that for 50 hours, you would need a battery with a capacity of around 6 watt hours.  That's about the size of a standard cell phone battery.

Comment: @alex.forencich thanks for that :) Interchangeable batteries are a real possibility if it comes down to that. For now, functionality is key

Comment: It would be nice to know your definition of 'small.'

Comment: @alex.forencich fair enough. Something like a Duracell 28A battery or two CR2032 watch batteries. Nothing as large as a AA battery or a typical 9V in size. No exact dimensions as of yet.

Comment: @JoshuaGranger point is, your problem definition is self-contradictionary, or at least unlikely. You say you want "low power", but at the same time you need to generate 150 V. Why? Is it true that you need to push exactly 1.5mA through an 100kOhm resistor?

Comment: @MarcusMüller not exactly. It's not that clear cut. The equivalent resistance of the load is 100k maximum, give or take. And I'm trying to generate a constant current to said load via the suggested battery types.

Comment: Right.  A CR2032 is about 0.6 Wh.  A 28A is also about 0.6 Wh.  So you would need 10 of them to get your 50 hour runtime.  And that's assuming 100% efficiency in your boost converter.

Comment: This looks like a decent reference: http://www.zbattery.com/zbattery/batteryinfo.html .  From what you've said, you need at least 6 Wh.  Probably more like 8-12 Wh.  You will need to use enough batteries of a sufficient size to get the run time you want.

Comment: @JoshuaGranger  If you dont include more specs it is pointless asking for a design. (Rule#1 for any budding design Engineer) (specs like signal shape, voltage, efficiency, battery life, budget, size...etc  ) Fuggedabout slim coin cells they have 3k ESR.  What's it for?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I don't disagree. However, I'm bound by confidentiality. I'm not trying to get a design outright - that would be less fun for me. I'm trying to get a better grasp of practical methods for accomplishing generally what I speak of.

Comment: signal shape, voltage, efficiency, battery life, budget

Comment: you didn't say even what is output energy level in watt-seconds or battery life? sounds rather amateurish spec

Comment: Well give specs or pay someone solid money to keep the confidentiality. It's either of those.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a bit back and forth, let's compile your requirements:

- Constant current source 1.5mA
- Maximum equiv. load resistance 100kOhm
- 50% duty cycle at 2 Hz
- Battery powered

So, we can directly infer a few things:

- You'll need some kind of DC/DC converter to convert your battery voltage (<20V) to the voltage you'll need to push 1.5mA through 100kOhm; namely, an step-up converter to 150V
- The power consumption of your load in on-state. is U·I = 1.5e2V·1.5e-3 A = 2.25e-1W = 0.225 W. With the 50 % duty cycle, that means your battery needs to supply an average of 112.5 mW – that's far more than a coin cell will do for more than a couple of seconds.

Normally, with modest output currents and at less extreme input/output voltage rations, step-up supply problems are often solved with inverting switch-mode power supplies, or simple boost topologies. However, nothing changes the fact that you'll need a flyback converter, here.

There's ICs that offer that functionality (flyback converters). For example, the TI LM2858 "simpleSwitcher" module.

Now you have a choice:

- Generate >150V and use a constant current sink (e.g. transistor pair in a "current mirror" configuration) drop exactly as much voltage as necessary to keep the current at a constant 1.5 mA
- Modify the schematic of the step-up converter, which is normally a voltage-feedback design, to be a current-feedback design

Since we're battery-based, the latter seems the best choice.

The 2Hz on/off switching is probably best done with a simple microcontroller, or something boring like a NE555 (watch the power consumption of the latter option).

Still note that you need to supply an average of 112.5W – a single AA-battery supplies 1.5V and has a capacity of about 2.8 Ah (according to German wikipedia), so it has a capacity of 4.2 Wh, and the four you'd need to get to 6V would have a total capacity of 16.8 Wh. With that, your circuit, at a **very** generously estimated step-up conversion efficiency of 70% would run a best-case of ca 11.5 Wh/0.1125 W ~= 100h off that.

Note that designing such a step-up converter isn't trivial – flybacks need custom-wound transformers, and at 150V, you want to make sure you don't electrocute yourself.

Comment: Great, very helpful. I guess one more requirement that I should mention is that no custom parts are allowed. I'm aiming to have my device built by a manufacturer once designed.

Comment: Well, good luck finding a ready-made flyback transformer that fits your need then! You can buy a few standard configurations of those, but it's usual to order made-to-specification transformers for this kind of supply. You don't have to wind those yourself!